# Kafka message ordering during consumer rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka

How message ordering is ensured during consumer rebalance. Suppose initially we have four partitions : p1 , p2 , p3, p4  and two consumers c1 and c2 (in same Group). So each consumer gets two partitions for example c1 : p1, p2  and c2 : p3, p4.

Now new consumers are added say c3 and c4, rebalancing happens so that each consumer gets one Partition like c1 : p1, c2:p2, c3:p3, c4:p4.

During this time there are chances that consumer c1 might be processing the message from partition p2 (before rebalancing)

and consumer c2 also starts processing p2 messages (after rebalancing)

Even though this is corner case, is this expected behaviour of message ordering ?

Comment: can you be a bit more clear regarding what the question is about message ordering?

Comment: message processing could be out of oder during rebalancing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> During this time there are chances that consumer c1 might be processing the message from partition p2 (before rebalancing)
>
> and consumer c2 also starts processing p2 messages (after rebalancing)

Yes. But how does this relate to message ordering? As long as there is no error, c1 should finish processing the current record (let's say with offset X) and after rebalance c2 will continue to process record with offset X+1.

And even if an error occurs and c1 fails to commit offset X -- c2 will reprocess some already processed messages but the order will still be preserved for partition p2.

A partitioned would only **not** be processed in-order, if a record with offset X1 would be processed before a record with offset X2 < X1. But that is never the case (you need to exclude reprocessing on caise of failure of course).

**Long story short:** *yes, this is behavoir by design*

If you build a stateless application and each record is processed independently this work very smooth. If you want state, you would need to make sure that the state of partition p2 it transferred from consumer c1 to c2 after rebalance (before c2 start to process data). Moving the state is actually a tough problem, and you should consider using **Kafka Streams** -- Kafka's stream processing library that can handling this for you automatically: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html

Comment: Thanks, In our use case for a given key, processing of message in order is   is important,  there could be few race conditions like after rebalance    1) C2 might have processed X+1 before C1 could finish processing X1  from partition p2.    2) C1 could fail to process X1 and C2 finishes processing X+1 .  Thanks  We will look into Kafka Streams

Comment: Both scenario you describe are not possible -- either C1 did finish processing before C2 starts to take over the partition, or C1 did not finish processing and C2 will retry the not completely processed record.
If consumer C1 is not dead and still processing record with offset X and the partitions is revoked and handed over to C2, when C1 tries to commit offset X the broker will not allow this because C1 does not own the partition anymore and thus the commit will fail with an exception.

Comment: And C2 will process record with offset X in parallel to C1. Thus, even if C1 would finish processing record X after C2 finished processing record X+1 it does not matter because C2 did process record X before it did process record X+1. Thus you could only end up with C2(X), C2(X+1) C1(X). Not sure if the second processing of X in C1 is harmful for your application or not.

Comment: I didn't know this case   "C1 tries to commit offset X the broker will not allow this because C1 does not own the partition anymore and thus the commit will fail with an exception".   Processing twice is ok , but it should be in the order. Thanks for details it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no message ordering across partitions, so this is an expected behavior where C1 consumes P1 before C2 takes over it and starts to read after a rebalance.

Comment: All consumers are in same group, it is message order with in same partition during rebalance